# how to get value from appSettings for given config file using c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, web-config

I'm giving `.config` file path and i want to retrieve appSetting value for `key=MYDATA` from that given `.config` file.

I tried following code but not getting expected.

```
//System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        //var classLibrary1AppSettings = (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");

        //config.AppSettings.File = "C:\\mydemo\\web.config";
```

> want to get value for `key=MYDATA`

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MYDATA"]`

Comment: You mean you want to be able to read _any_ config, not your own application's config?

Comment: this will give me data for current project web.config, I want a value from `C:\\mydemo\\web.config`

Comment: @CodeCaster perfect that is what i want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691636/write-appsettings-in-external-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4746/1663001 perhaps then

Comment: no answer working for me :( can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I able to manage it:

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "C:\\mydemo\\web.config";

            System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            AppSettingsSection section = (AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("appSettings");
            if (section.Settings.AllKeys.Any(key => key == "MYDATA"))
            {
                section.Settings["MYDATA"].Value = updateConfigId;
                configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            }
```