# How to determine path of appsettings file in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am referencing my web app's settings using a `configSource` attribute for the `appSettings` element:

```
<appSettings configSource="c:/settings/customer-settings.config"></appSettings>
```

I would now like to access this path programmatically using a Configuration object:

```
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

However the `configSource` path does not seem to be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `file` attribute instead of `configSource`. `configSource` requires your config to live inside the application path, while `file` does not have this restriction.

some more info: [ASP.NET web.config: configSource vs. file attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940004/asp-net-web-config-configsource-vs-file-attributes)